# Hemicontinuity of correspondence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

I have a correspondece $f$ of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that gives me $\textrm{sin}(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $[-1,1]$ if $x=0$. I have to test whether this function is continuous or not, using hemicontinuity. To disprove that it is a lower hemicontinious function, I defined a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n=1/n \cdot \pi$, so I get the sequence of the direct image of $x$, $y_n$, such that $y_n=0$ for all $n$.

Consider a $b$ that belongs to $[-1,1]$ and is different from $0$. Then there isn't any sequence of $y \rightarrow b$. Is that correct?

Comment: There is such a sequence. Let use e such that $b=\sin(e)$. Then the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{e+2n\pi}$ verify $f(x_n) = b$

Comment: There isnt since yn is the sequence of the image of xn.